# Django парсер для обновления значений в БД

Tags: python, django, парсер, parse

в Django есть профиль, каждый профиль имеет пункт A и B, в данном пункте должны быть определенные цифровые значения полученные с сайта. Требуется, чтобы после регистрации пользователя, если поле A заполнено, происходит регистрация, сразу парсится сайт и в B поле записывается значение, далее каждые 60 минут по определенному сайту парсилось значение с A значением и в поле B добавлялся полученный результат. Если A пустое, то после обновления профиля и заполнения A поля, происходило тоже самое.

Пример:

models.py

```
class Profile:
     A = models.CharField()
     B = models.IntegerField()
```

Далее url(ссылка)/A.
Результат парсинга добавляется в B.

Если было значение в поле B, то после парсинга оно заменяется на актуальное, если B = результату парсинга, то ничего не происходит и заного сбрасывается таймер на 60 мин.

Если требуется доп информация, обязательно дополню.

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: В чем именно заключается ваш вопрос?

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров, требуется реализовать парсер внутри Django. Не могу понять реализацию. Пробовал в views сделать с time.sleep на 60 мин, но не пойму как сделать постоянный парсер и обновлением информации по каждому пользователю. Требуется именно не для одного пользователя это реализовать, а для всех. Чтобы по всей БД пользователей каждый проверялся.

Comment: Если вам нужно делать эти проверки постоянно в фоне - посмотрите в сторону очередей задач. Например, Celery, который будет запускать задачи по расписанию.

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров понял, спасибо, попробую посмотреть в эту сторону, надеюсь получится